# NLog is not able to create logs in a Documents folder

Tags: .net, .net-core, nlog

my Nlog configuration for logging to file looks like this

```
"allLogFile": {
  "type": "file",
  "fileName": "C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Documents\\logs\\Log.txt",
  "archiveFileName": "C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Documents\\logs\\Log.{#}.txt",
  "archiveNumbering": "Date",
  "archiveEvery": "Day",
  "archiveDateFormat": "yyyyMMdd",
  "layout": "${longdate}| ${uppercase:${level}}|  ${logger}|  ${message}   ${exception:format=tostring}"
}
```

It does not create the logs file, but if I change the path to `"fileName": "C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\logs\\Log.txt"` then it works file, Ive tried several other locations like Pictures, Downloads, C:, does not work as well, for Documents Ive also tried `${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments}\\logs\\Log.txt`.

My first guess is maybe permission rights problem? Also I have `"throwConfigExceptions": true,` in the config, it throws exceptions if some fields in config is wrong, but doesnt throw for this problem (I guess its only exceptions for config rather than writting)

So is there a way to make it able to write in other directories liek Documents?

Comment: That config doesn't create the log file in the Documents folder, it creates it in the logs folder.  Remove "logs" to verify your claim.

Comment: @HansPassant well I mean it would create the logs in folder Documents/logs wouldnt it? I mean with the Desktop folder config it indeed does create logs in the Desktop/logs folder

Comment: `"throwConfigExceptions": true` will only throw exception during the loading of NLog-configuration, but not during the actual logging. Try enabling [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and look for clues. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: @RolfKristensen ooooooh good to findout about InternalLogging, will check it out thanks!